# Detect circular segment in the image

Tags: python, matlab, detection, shapes, hough-transform

I am trying to determine the circle parameters, using its slice, visible in the image. I want to know the radius, coordinates of center and draw the full circle (on the bigger picture of course). I've tried to use **imfindcircles** with Hough Transformation. Unfortunately, it looks like the slice of the circle is not big enough, and the algorithm does not recognize it as the full circle.

[image: The fragment of white circle on black background]

```
clear all;
close all;

figure();
image = imread('circle3.jpg');
imshow(image);

Rmin = 10;
Rmax = 10000;

[centersBright, radiiBright] = imfindcircles(image,[Rmin 
Rmax],'ObjectPolarity','bright','Method','TwoStage','Sensitivity',0.98,'EdgeThreshold',0.9);

viscircles(centersBright, radiiBright,'Color','b');
```

I have changed the sensivity, threshold, Rmin, Rmax, even the method, but still, nothing happens. How can I detect this circle, if not in Matlab, then maybe in Python?

Comment: This is not the type of problem where Hough is suitable for, but it’s actually a lot simpler than those problems. You need to get some pixels at the edge (find pixels that are white and have a black neighbor), get a list of their coordinates, then fit a circle through those coordinates. If you have only 3 points, the fit is trivial, if you use more points you need to do a least squat fit, but you’ll get a more precise result.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I've been thinking about it as well. But what would be the most optimal way to create such a circle, that would fit into those coordinates? I need some function, that draws the circle crossing three given points on picture.

Comment: [How to fit a circle to a set of points](https://www.google.com/search?q=fit+a+circle+to+points).